# inconvertible types found : int required: java.lang.Short

Tags: java, types

I was given this source code and asked to compile it: it fails with the error " inconvertible types found   : int required: java.lang.Short".

The code does a bitwise shift to convert some hashed (I think) values to integer. The compiler fails when encountering this statement "s >>>= 5;"

```
...   try {...

    // Query data
    SelectQuery = "select "
     + "... " 
     + "from " 
     + "subscrib a, "
     + "account b "
     +"where " 
     +"a.cardid>0  "
     + "and "
     + "b.camc_card_id>0 "
     + "and "
     + "a.cardid=b.camc_card_id " 
     +"and "
     + "a.cardid >= ? and a.cardid <= ?";

    CApStmt = CAconn.prepareStatement(SelectQuery);
    // We set the card id ranges
    CApStmt.setLong(1, mincardversion[0]);
    CApStmt.setLong(2, maxcardversion[0]);

    CArs = CApStmt.executeQuery();

    while (CArs.next()) {
     // We retrieve all columns from source table
     long SUBID = CArs.getLong(1);
     Date NEWCARDDATE = CArs.getDate(2);
     int CSSNUMBER = CArs.getInt(3);
     String ZIPCODE = CArs.getString(4);
     int SUBREGIONS = CArs.getBinaryStream(5).read();
     int CALLBACKDAY = CArs.getBinaryStream(6).read();

     /*
      * This field contains two-byte bitmap with the following
      * format: Bits 15-11 : Hour <- Bits 10-5 : Minutes <- Bits
      * 4-0 : Seconds/2
      */
     Short s = CArs.getShort(7);

     /* Bits 0-4 : Seconds (bitwise AND operation) */
     int secs = s & 0x1F;
     int seconds = secs / 2;

     /* Bits 5-10 : Minutes (bitwise AND operation) */
     s >>>= 5;
     int min = s & 0x1F;
     int minutes = min * 60;
..........
```

The original author of the code swears up and down that it used to compile but cannot help me. I know just enough to compile a class or build a package.

Note that I removed the SQL query from this code snippet due to its size...Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the short value as `short`, not `Short`. Even if the `getShort()` method returns the wrapper, it will be [autounboxed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). (And, in fact, why not use `int` ?)

Comment: Thank you. `short` instead of `Short` is all it took.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason to use an object?  If you used a primitive *short* instead of *Short* it should work.